# "Required version of distribute not available" when installing IMAPClient

Tags: 10.04

I'm receiving the following error when I run the command "easy_install imapclient":

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package distribute
root@localhost:/var/www/somedir# easy_install imapclient
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for imapclient
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/imapclient/
Reading http://freshfoo.com/wiki/CodeIndex
Reading http://imapclient.freshfoo.com/
Best match: IMAPClient 0.8.1
Downloading http://freshfoo.com/projects/IMAPClient/IMAPClient-0.8.1.zip
Processing IMAPClient-0.8.1.zip
Running IMAPClient-0.8.1/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-BmlBbm/IMAPClient-0.8.1/egg-dist-tmp-5OVaNN
The required version of distribute (>=0.6.24) is not available,
and can't be installed while this script is running. Please
install a more recent version first, using
'easy_install -U distribute'.

(Currently using distribute 0.6.14 (/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages))
error: Setup script exited with 2
```

Any thoughts on what might be causing this?

I've tried running "easy_install -U distribute" as suggested in the above output, which returns the following output:

```
install_dir /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/
Searching for distribute
Reading http://pypi.python.org/simple/distribute/
Reading http://packages.python.org/distribute
Best match: distribute 0.6.24
Processing distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg
distribute 0.6.24 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing easy_install script to /usr/local/bin
Installing easy_install-2.6 script to /usr/local/bin

Using /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/distribute-0.6.24-py2.6.egg
Processing dependencies for distribute
Finished processing dependencies for distribute
```

I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 64-bit Server if that helps any.

Comment: +1 for both of you! thanks so much for taking the time to figure this out and sharing the knowledge! X-Cubed gets the "correct answer" rewarded to him for a clear cut and precise example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the *right way* to do it, but it worked for me. I modified /usr/bin/easy_install script and removed the version constraint for distribute, so it now looks like this:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# EASY-INSTALL-ENTRY-SCRIPT: 'distribute','console_scripts','easy_install'
__requires__ = 'distribute'
import sys
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(
        load_entry_point('distribute', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
    )
```

Comment: It should be noted that this edit allows you to successfully run "easy_install -U distribute", which in turn allows you to then run "easy_install imapclient".

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem on the same version of Ubuntu (but 32-bit instead of 64).

The problem is that our old version of pip and easy_install is trying to install newer python modules that require newer versions of `distribute` than our version of pip/easy_install likes. And like X-Cubed pointed out, easy_install (hence pip) requires a specific, old version of distribute. X-Cubed's solution worked for me, but instead of eliminating the version I set it to a minimum, so that other easy_installs (and pips) can require lower versions, if necessary. So the /usr/bin/easy_install lines that changed are:

```
__requires__ = 'distribute>0.6.10'
```

and

```
load_entry_point('distribute>0.6.10', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
```

Presumably `distribute` plays nice and is **always** reverse compatible. If so this will cause fewer problems than easy_install requiring a specific version of distribute that doesn't work for many python modules.

Then I reran pip for my requirements (`pip install requirements/*`) which needed the `URLObject` python module, and it got through the version conflict issue just fine after I made this change. (so X-Cubed was at least partially right and probably 100% right).

This sed will also fix it

```
sudo sed -i -r -e 's/distribute==/distribute>/g' /usr/bin/easy_install
```